# Match list of words without the list of chars around

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, regex-group

I have this regex

```
(?:$|^| )(one|common|word|or|another)(?:$|^| )
```

which matches fine unless the two words are next to each other.

```
One one's more word'word common word or another word more another 

More and more years to match one or more other strings

And common word things and or
```

In the above it matches `one` in line two but not the `or` just next to it. Same for `common` and `word` int the third line.

Live Example: http://regex101.com/r/hV3wQ3

I believe it's something to do with the non-matching groups' number. But, I am not sure how to achieve the end goal of matching all the list of words without any char around them.

I do not want the `one` in `one's` or the word in `word'word` to be matched.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Since your capture groups define explicitly one character on either side of the common word, it's looking for `space` `word` `space` and then when it doesn't find another `space`, it fails.

In this case, since you don't want to match all the characters word boundary's would catch (period, apostrophe, etc.) you need to use a bit of trickery with lookaheads, lookbehinds, and non-capture groups. Try this:

```
(?:^|(?<= ))(one|common|word|or|another)(?:(?= )|$)
```

http://regex101.com/r/cM9hD8

Word boundaries are still simpler to implement, so for reference sake, you could also do this (though it would include `'`, `.`, etc.).

```
\b(one|common|word|or|another)\b
```

Comment: I've updated the question. That's the reason I'm not using word boundary. It matches `word'word` and `one's`.

Comment: OK that makes sense - in that case I've updated the answer with a new expression and link for you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `(?:[\s]|^)(one|common|word|or|another)(?=[\s]|$)` instead.

It will not match `one's`  ,  `someone` ,etc...

Check **[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/uA2xR5)**

Comment: I don't want to match `one's`. That's why I don't use \b

Comment: Now the problem is `word'word` being matched. :(

Comment: It doesn't work if the words are next to each other. it matches `common` in `common word` but not `word`. Remus's answer does the job exactly. Thanks for your suggestions.