# Match an expression as a list

Tags: regex

I have a string that I am trying to create a regular expression to match the assignment name "People" and its list of people

`People = "Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "David", "Erica", "Fred";`

**Conditions:**

- The expression name "People" must be returned
- Any number of names must be returned separately (in groups)

I have looked to see if I could find something similar
[Match list of words without the list of chars around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448139/match-list-of-words-without-the-list-of-chars-around)
But I am not sure if this is the correct thing, or how to apply it.

**The Regex expression I have tried**

`( \"([A-Z0-9]+)\",?)`

This seems to match all of the individual names, however I am not sure how I can retrieve "People" in a separate group.

Is this a case for lookaround expressions in Regex? If so, how can it be implemented?

Comment: Maybe all you need is just `\w+`?

Comment: What programming language are you using here?

Comment: A capture group can only return one value. You need to do this in two steps: Step 1 retrieve People and the entire list of names as 2 groups. Step 2 split up the list of names.

Comment: Besides pulling these values; would you need to validate that the input is exactly as given structure?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen C#/.NET

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, that would work, however it doesn't satisfy the condition of returning the Expression name "People".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the pattern even more specific, but in this case you might use the [CapturesCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.capturecollection?view=net-6.0) in C# by using a repeated capture group:

```
\b(?<name>[A-Za-z0-9]+)\s*=\s*(?:\"(?<people>[A-Za-z0-9]+)\",?\s*)+;
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qyeWQ0/1) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/ZrfFRQ)

Example to get the values:

```
string pattern = @"\b(?<name>[A-Za-z0-9]+)\s*=\s*(?:\""(?<people>[A-Za-z0-9]+)\"",?\s*)+;";
string input = @"People = ""Alice"", ""Bob"", ""Charlie"", ""David"", ""Erica"", ""Fred"";";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
var name = match.Groups["name"].Value;
var strings = match.Groups["people"].Captures.Select(c => c.Value);

Console.WriteLine(name);

foreach (String s in strings)
{
    Console.WriteLine("-> "+ s);
}
```

Output

```
People
-> Alice
-> Bob
-> Charlie
-> David
-> Erica
-> Fred
```